# How to compare .getCurrentTextColor() with Hex Code (Android)

Tags: java, android, hex

just wondering how I can compare the current color of a TextView with a Hex code. The code snippet looks like this:

```
public void topButtonClicked(View view) {
    if(color_top.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.parseColor("#000000")) {
        score_top += 1;
        button_top.setText("Score "+score_top);
    } else {    
        //
    }
```

Would be awesome if someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works just fine as it is!
I was the Hex code I used was just the wrong one..